# How to have optional modules in a package

Tags: python

I am making a package based on Pyaudio to handle some audio processing and playback,

I want to make an optional Gui class in gui.py (Gui class) that is a gui console based on PyQt5.

However, since the package is mainly an audio related package. I would like to make Gui class an optional import so that when users import the main module without PyQt5 dependency, they could still use the module except the gui part of course.

```
src
----__init__.py
----myaudio.py
----mygui.py


#__init__.py
from .myaudio import Pyaudio
try:
    from .mygui import Mygui
except:
    raise Warning("no PyQt5 found, Mygui not available")


#mygui.py
import PyQt5
import myaudio
```

Is that ok to just use try in **init** so it will skip the entire import mygui if exception is caught? myaudio is completely independent from mygui. I am not sure what is considered a good practice in this case.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So why do you need to import your submodules in `__init__.py`?

Why not just let your users import them as `from your_package.myaudio import Pyaudio`. In this case, you don't need to do anything.

And if they want to use GUI, they just use `from your_package.mygui import Mygui`.

Comment: As I plan to have a few more class in the future. I want to be able to do from my_package import * or simply import my_package, which can include all the modules, except the one without dependencies of course.

Comment: Well, `from x import *` is not a good idea as it will pollute the namespace. Whatever, you can import everything in `__init__.py`, and let users manually import `from x.mygui import Mygui` when they explicitly want to use GUI.

Comment: With your suggestion, will it returns error during python setup.py install or pip install if PyQt5 dependency is not available? Thanks